# Sed remove matches on 2+ lines

Tags: android, shell, scripting, posix, gnu

So I'm trying to remove "deep_buffer," source within certain sinks that match, such as "Earpiece" and "Wired Headset". How would I do this when there's a line break between? I'm looking for 2 ways. First, matching out the exclusions and patching the rest and/or just patching just the ones I want such as the ones mentioned above (from the match). I'm using posix shell in android.

Original code:

```
<routes>
    <route type="mix" sink="Earpiece"
           sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,direct_pcm,compressed_offload,voip_rx"/>
    <route type="mix" sink="Speaker"
           sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,direct_pcm,compressed_offload,voip_rx"/>
    <route type="mix" sink="Wired Headset"
           sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,direct_pcm,compressed_offload,voip_rx"/>
    <route type="mix" sink="Wired Headphones"
           sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,direct_pcm,compressed_offload,voip_rx"/>
    <route type="mix" sink="Line"
           sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,direct_pcm,compressed_offload,voip_rx"/>
    <route type="mix" sink="HDMI"
           sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,multichannel,direct_pcm,compressed_offload"/>
    <route type="mix" sink="Proxy"
           sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,multichannel,direct_pcm,compressed_offload"/>
    <route type="mix" sink="FM"
           sources="primary output"/>
    <route type="mix" sink="BT SCO All"
           sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,direct_pcm,compressed_offload,voip_rx"/>
    <route type="mix" sink="Telephony Tx"
           sources="voice_tx"/>
    <route type="mix" sink="primary input"
           sources="Wired Headset Mic,BT SCO Headset Mic,FM Tuner,Telephony Rx"/>
    <route type="mix" sink="surround_sound"
           sources="Built-In Mic,Built-In Back Mic"/>
    <route type="mix" sink="record_24"
           sources="Built-In Mic,Built-In Back Mic,Wired Headset Mic"/>
    <route type="mix" sink="voice_rx"
           sources="Telephony Rx"/>
</routes>
```

Expected output would remove deep_buffer from matched sinks like "wired headphones" and "wired headset" like below (but only the matched ones):

```
   <routes>
        <route type="mix" sink="Earpiece"
               sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,direct_pcm,compressed_offload,voip_rx"/>
        <route type="mix" sink="Speaker"
               sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,direct_pcm,compressed_offload,voip_rx"/>
        <route type="mix" sink="Wired Headset"
               sources="primary output,raw,direct_pcm,compressed_offload,voip_rx"/>
        <route type="mix" sink="Wired Headphones"
               sources="primary output,raw,direct_pcm,compressed_offload,voip_rx"/>
        <route type="mix" sink="Line"
               sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,direct_pcm,compressed_offload,voip_rx"/>
        <route type="mix" sink="HDMI"
               sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,multichannel,direct_pcm,compressed_offload"/>
        <route type="mix" sink="Proxy"
               sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,multichannel,direct_pcm,compressed_offload"/>
        <route type="mix" sink="FM"
               sources="primary output"/>
        <route type="mix" sink="BT SCO All"
               sources="primary output,raw,deep_buffer,direct_pcm,compressed_offload,voip_rx"/>
        <route type="mix" sink="Telephony Tx"
               sources="voice_tx"/>
        <route type="mix" sink="primary input"
               sources="Wired Headset Mic,BT SCO Headset Mic,FM Tuner,Telephony Rx"/>
        <route type="mix" sink="surround_sound"
               sources="Built-In Mic,Built-In Back Mic"/>
        <route type="mix" sink="record_24"
               sources="Built-In Mic,Built-In Back Mic,Wired Headset Mic"/>
        <route type="mix" sink="voice_rx"
               sources="Telephony Rx"/>
    </routes>
```

Comment: What is your expected output/

Comment: Updated original question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but here's a quick-and-dirty Perl program that removes the string "deep-buffer," from only the lines following those containing the strings "Earpiece" and "Wired Headset".  I tried to write it so that the logic is easy to follow.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$flag = "0";
while ( <> ) {
    if ( $flag eq "1" )
    {
        s/deep_buffer,//g;
        $flag = "0";
    }
    elsif ( /"Earpiece"/ || /"Wired Headset"/ )
    {
        $flag = "1";
    }
    print;
}
exit;
```